# Como configurar o terminal do VSCode?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

Eu estou tentando configurar meu VSCode para que eu possa instalar bibliotecas através do terminal integrado mas estou tendo problemas, parece que o VSCode não "sincroniza" com o terminal padrão.

A princípio eu estava utilizando virtualenv apenas. Criava meu ambiente virtual e quando abria meu workspace no VSCode era capaz de configurar o interpretador como sendo o venv criado. Já o terminal ativava o venv quando criado mas rodava um python 2.x, não me deixava instalar nada por ele, sempre reclamava que o pip estava desatualizado mas não me deixava atualizar o pip.

Achei que o problema poderia ser a questão de ter duas versões de python diferentes dentro do meu venv então optei por testar o pyenv. Reinstalei e configurei tudo, adicionei os comandos necessários ao .bashrc e poderia ativar meu pyenv externamente. No VSCode era capaz de configurar o interpretador (barra de tarefas) para meu pyenv criado mas o terminal continua não estando alinhado ao terminal do meu linux... não aceita o pyenv como comando e continua rodando em uma versão 2.X do python.

Estou tentando solucionar agora utilizando o comando

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux":{ 
        "VSCODE_INTEGRATED_TERMINAL": "true"
    }
```

Mas quando utilizo o comando abaixo para verificar, não aparece True

```
echo $VSCODE_INTEGRATED_TERMINAL
```

Já tentei abrir o vscode direto do diretório e já tentei abrir como worspace e como folder...

Alguém já teve algum problema assim com o terminal do VSCode? Como conseguiu solucionar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com ajuda de uma amiga e resolvi deixar registrado. Estava usando um comando errado no json, editei o settings.json e adicionei o seguinte comando:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]
```

Agora o terminal esta apontando diretamente para o Shell principal do meu linux!

Comment: Me ajudou aqui também!
Obrigado por compartilhar a resolução!

Answer (score -4):

no windows 10, aparece a opçao de instalar umas extençoes, mas no vscode tem como atraves do menu a  quarta aba o VER EM PORTUGUES, OU VEW EM SEGUIDA EXTENSOES.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).